# What is “access control” with X Server?

Tags: x-server, access-control

What is an access control restriction with an X Server?

There is the `-ac` option that "disable access control restrictions" with e.g. Xephyr.

I saw some example using that option, but I have no idea how it works and why it is necessary.

Can you show me a example in which case I should use this option and in which case I shouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use this option if your X server is accessible from the open internet. It makes it possible for anyone to watch what goes on in your X session.

I suppose it's useful if you have an intranet and you want to pop up windows across machines without bothering with authentication.

Comment: So if I have X Server and client in a same computer, then I don't need the option and must not use it, is that right?

Comment: Your server is probably accessible from beyond your computer, even if you don't use it that way. The question is, do you have any reason you _need_ to disable it? I doubt it, so leave it on.

Comment: @alexis - by "accessible from the open internet", you mean `Xserver` has open tcp/udp ports on `0.0.0.0`, which can be seen using `netstat -lptun`, or you mean something else ?

Comment: I mean, if your X server is on `example.com`, could *I* pop up a window on it from my laptop, by typing `xterm -display example.com:0.0`? If I could, you need access control to keep me from eavesdropping on your kepstrokes.

Answer (score 1):

Many X servers use X11 reference code and thus have the same command line options. Look at the [`Xserver(1)`](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/Xserver.1.xhtml) man page for commonly-supported options. Quoting it:

> `−ac`
>   disables host-based access control mechanisms. Enables access by any host, and permits any host to modify the access control list. Use with extreme caution. This option exists primarily for running test suites remotely.

Host-based access control is a thing of the past (it's pretty much always done with [cookies](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xauth.1.xhtml) now), but host-based access control needs to be always off (`xhost -`), not always-off-and-you-can't-effectively-turn-it-on as with `X -ac`.